# TIleMill/Mapbox Hover boxes on multiple layers

Tags: javascript, leaflet, layer, mapbox, tilemill

I was hoping someone might be able to steer me in the right direction with something that's been giving me a headache.

So, in TileMill, you can have different polygon layers activate at different zoom levels. This is great, of course, but the problem is that you can't have a hover box for more than one of those layers. Not very useful.

To clarify: At zoom level 4, say, I want to see a state-level layer and, when holding my mouse above Missouri I want a box to appear saying something like 'Missouri: an awesome state.' Then at zoom 7, I want to see counties, and when I hover over Boone County, I want to see something like 'Boone County: an awesome county.'

In TileMill, you can have hover boxes for either the state layer OR the county layer, not both.

I've done many hours of googling and playing with code, but haven't figured out how to do this.  [The Leaflet plugin](http://moonlite.github.io/Leaflet.MultiTileLayer/) that allegedly lets you incorporate multiple tile layers doesn't seem to work. Then again, my JS skills are severely lacking, so I could be wrong.

Has anyone here achieved this? How? Do I need to learn some serious Javascript, or is there a more plug-and-play way to do it?

Thanks much for your time.

Fedor

Comment: Instead of writing "The Leaflet plugin that allegedly lets you incorporate multiple tile layers doesn't seem to work." - it would be better to say how and what you tried, any errors you saw, and other information that would help others help you.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend making separate map layers, uploading them to Mapbox, then taking advantage of Mapbox's server-side compositing of interactivity to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using [UTFGrids](https://www.mapbox.com/developers/utfgrid/) for the hover/click events.

In order to differentiate based on zoom level you want multiple UTFGrids, one for zoom levels 1-4, another for 5-7, etc.